# Get Magento CMS pages and widget in wordpress home page

Tags: cms, widgets, wordpress

I am excellent in wordpress. I am new to magento. I am interested to learn magento.
I added 3 widgets in content part of cms page. Now i need to display it in wordpress homepage. Can you pls help to find solution?

```
{widget type="meigeewidgets/featuredcategory" featured_category="category/3" template="meigee/meigeewidgets/slider_small.phtml" products_amount="15" slider_small_speed="1000" slider_small_easing="easeInQuad" widget_small_id="6615"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure as to what you are trying to accomplish but I'll name a few possibilities anyway.

1. **APIs** Magento comes with a great API layer that you can use to get content in and out of Magento. Unfortunately is not part of that API but there is however [documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html) on how to build your own API to extend Magento.
2. **Magento Models** another option is to use the Magento models. This will require you to have access to the file `./app/Mage.php` and from there on you can retrieve all the information you want. Please see the code snippet below.

*code example for getting CMS page data*

```
   require '/path/to/app/Mage.php';
   Mage::app('admin');

   $page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('about-magento-demo-store', 'identifier');
   var_dump($page->getData());
```

1. **3th party integration** Whatever you come up with, somebody else already did it once. Check out these extension (I haven't worked with any of them but just try them out and see if any of them work for you.)

   - http://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/
   - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration.html
   - http://www.mwi-plugin.com/

Comment: Thanks, I understood the code. I added widgets in cms page. Now how to display that widget? The widget contains slider1,2 and 3. I need to display that slider containing products.

Comment: Please send me functions page in magento like wordpress codex.

Comment: You can check the Magento Wiki http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/ if you want but Magento is somewhat bigger then WP in its functions and classes. I'm not very sure what you mean with your comment about widgets. Please either update your question with more details or post a new question after closing this one.

Comment: Yes, i updated my question. Can you please check it?